# Minimum bounty is 100 with deleted answer

Tags: support, bounty

It seems that a question which i answered myself, and then deleted the answer still appears as "answered by myself" and thus requires a minimal bounty or 100 reputation instead of 50.

I know and understand the reason where bounty minimum was increased to 100 for self-answered questions, but what if the answer is now deleted ?

Is that a bug or a feature ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This is a feature.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116476/189912)

> This is indeed a new feature (introduced in [September 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59446/189912)) to [prevent abuse of the bounty system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105275/189912).This is mentioned explicitly in a few [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105639/189912) [answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64824/189912) but, as far as I can tell, **not in FAQs**.

One way this abuse was done was:

Someone would post an answer on someone else's question, and then place a bounty on the question to draw attention to it. He would then gain more upvotes from the publicity than he spent on the bounty. The spend was raised to 100 to discourage this.

The reason it applies even if your answer is deleted, is because you might still undelete the answer.

Comment: Isn't there a way to permanently delete the answer ? since it was kind of a mistake where I thought the pproblem resolved where it wasn't.

Comment: Not without involving developers, and this generally isn't done unless there are privacy or legal reasons to destroy the post.

Comment: Well i guess my question isn't worth the reputation loos. Too bad. Thanks.

Comment: There are [other ways](http://serverfault.com/help/no-one-answers) to draw attention to your question. Editing it is the primary way. Add more information about what you've found out. For instance, you can add that you tried that thing and you thought it worked at first but it didn't.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but my (wrong) abnswer was due to a confusion between 2 hosts so that's very unrelated. I have also done the most documentation about my problem I possibly could. No I just think my problem is too uncommon/obsure to inspire anyone.

Comment: What's to prevent somebody from creating a bounty first and then answer the question?

Comment: @kasperd Nothing. It happens all the time, in fact. But that's not the situation being discussed here.